# Proof using the epsilon delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Can someone please explain to me how to prove the following:

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}F(x) = L $ and if 
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}H(x) = H$ such that $H(x)\ne0$ for all $x$ in the domain, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}F(x)/H(x) = L/H$.

I dont want the whole proof, just give me some hints so that I can work on the proof on my own.
Thanks!

Comment: The condition that $H(x)$ is non-zero for all $x$ is not sufficient.. you'll need that the limit $H$ is non zero as well.

Comment: okay, thanks. I actually missed copying that part of the question on this website

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{F(x)}{H(x)} - \frac{L}{H} = \frac{F(x)H - L H(x)}{H(x)H}  = \frac{(F(x)H  - LH ) +(LH- L H(X))}{H(x)H}.$$

Then show that the two summands in the numerator become small, while the denominator stays away from $0$ so that the quotient in total is small.

(Note: I assume the limit $H$ is also assumed non-zero. This is not explicitly stated and not a consequence of the fact that $H(x)$ is non-zero.)

Comment: I tried doing it but somehow I am not able to make the summand less than epsilon.

Comment: What I did was that I used the triangle inequality to make both the summands less the sum of the absolute value of the individual summands. after this I am not able to figuire it out

Comment: This is fine. So then let us consider the two summands. the first is $|F(X)H - LH| = |H (F(X)- L)|$. So if $|(F(X)- L)| \le \epsilon$ then this is $\le H \epsilon $ and the other is $\le L \epsilon$ if $|H - H(x)| \le \epsilon $. Thus in total you get a bound of $(L+ H) \epsilon$ if both $|H - H(x)| \le \epsilon $ and $|(F(X)- L)| \le \epsilon$. This leaves the denominator. Here try to show that for $x$ close to $c$ you have $|H(x)| \ge H/2$ for example.